# Symfony2 Assetic files and Missing routes in Windows

Tags: windows-7, symfony, assetic

I have a Linux machine, and a Windows 7 machine, each of which is using the exact same code (they are both using the same git repo). I am running the Symfony2 code on both servers in the dev environment.

The website loads and runs just great on the Linux server. On the Windows 7 server (my local laptop) the server seems to be missing all the routes it needs to render the site correctly. For example:

1. None of the CSS and JS files are loading on the site. They are throwing a 404 page not found error.
2. If I attempt to navigate to any other pages from the home or landing page, a 404 error is always thrown: The requested URL was not found on the server.

I've cleared the cache, and run through the app/check.php on the windows box, but to no avail. I'm wondering if the Windows server setup needs to be modified in some way so the routing works as expected? I'm thinking that the problem is the routing on the Windows server, as the requested URLs can't ever be found.

Any ideas on where I can go to find a solution or any tests I can perform to track down the issue?
Thanks,
Derrick

Comment: Are you using Apache (or nginx) on both setup ? MIf you use IIS, I would have a look around if I were you. I would also check apache configuration on both environment.

Comment: I'm using Apache on both servers. As far as I can tell, the httpd.conf files are the same on both. The linux server has more modules activated than the windows server. However the windows server did pass Symfony2's check.php. The php.ini files also look the same on both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the httpd.conf file, you must be sure that:

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

is active. In my windows distribution of apache 2.2, it was commented out. I'll suggest to Symfony2 that they add this module to their check.php file for future developers. I'm guessing they just assume that it will always be enabled in the apache distributions.